# Eslint rule for enforcing spaces around a ternary statement's colon?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Is there an eslint rule to check that ternary colons have a space around them? There is a [multiline-ternary](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/multiline-ternary) rule, but I can't find one about the spacing.

Example of bad formatting:

```
showAreas ? areas: undefined
//               ^ missing a space
```

Example of good formatting:

```
showAreas ? areas : undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule for enforcing spaces [Space Infix Ops](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops)